# Is there a definitive direction for going “full ass” relative to going half-ass?

Tags: offensive-language, derivational-morphology

I’ve never heard “full ass” as an actual term anywhere, but I wondered about it since the actual term “half-ass” implies there should be a theoretical meaning for going full. If “half-ass” means insufficient work/performance, then would going full mean maximally sufficient? Or since “ass” is generally treated as bad, does going full mean maximally insufficient (*i.e.* 0% complete and/or worst-quality work)?

There’s a [similar query](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/105133/105500), but its answers solely focus on “half-ass,” with passing mentions of a “full(y) ass” without pinning down a definitive direction.

Comment: You have ***whole-ass***
adjective , adverb US slang,

 
complete or completely:
*It's not a snack; it's a whole-ass meal.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whole-ass

Comment: You can do whatever you want with this type of thing in English: full-assed, quarter-assed,  whole-assed x.  With or without the past participle form.

Comment: Now that I think about it, *full ass* ought to mean completely foolish.  Perhaps John Lawler will come and say something about polarity.

Answer (score 1):

User "Archy Will He 何魏奇" explained it in [an answer to that previous question:](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105133/etymology-of-half-assed/105136#105136)

> According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=half-assed&allowed_in_frame=0), *half-assed* made its first appearance in the early 20th century. It is most likely a mispronunciation of the word *haphazard*.
>
> > half-assed (adj.)
> >
> > "ineffectual," 1932, perhaps a humorous mispronunciation of haphazard.
>
> With this in mind, I don't think *full-assed* or *fully assed* would make any sense.
> Though [some people](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=full-ass) may probably still use it like how the word *mentee* is invented by adding a suffix after [back-forming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backformation) the word *mentor*. And that is rather ridiculous. Unlike *professor* or *escalator*, the word *mentor* is originated from the Greek word *Méntōr* which is the name of the son of Anchialus and Asopis.

As "user 66974," the backformation "whole-ass" exists; it means maximally sufficient, not maximally insufficient,
[as Cambridge explains.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whole-ass)

Comment: False: “It is most likely a mispronunciation of the word haphazard.”