# Does anyone have a good idiom for when someone asks you to guess what they are doing/thinking but you are not interested in making an effort to guess?

Tags: expressions

Like say if I ask someone what’s are you using that for and they say guess I’m looking for a good idiom that indicates I’m not interested in guessing like “I’m not a mind reader” springs to mind, but does anyone have any others similar to this ?

Comment: Thank you for asking. There are actually several problems here. First, some information we need to help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Comment: Second, a word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 15):

It's not an idiom really, but you can always say "**[I give up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/give-up)**". What's nice about this is that it's polite and non-confrontational.

For example:

> "[...] Guess what?"
>   "I give up?"
>   <sub>[Alien Ice](https://books.google.com/books?id=geqKAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&dq=guess+what+"i+give+up")</sub>

> “Well, guess who I met there?”
>   “I give up.”
>   “Russell Canton.”
>   <sub>[Why Did She Have to Die?](https://books.google.com/books?id=aiZXBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&dq=guess+what+"i+give+up")</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Not much of an idiom, but perhaps "I'm in no mood for games."?

Comment: This makes sense, but sounds a little formal. Perhaps "Not in the mood." instead?

Comment: @FreddieR - I would not take this as formal.

Answer (score 3):

I usually say "Can't be arsed", but again that's not an idiom.

Edit: I've just been corrected. It indeed is an idiom! Sorry, my bad

Comment: Seems like an idiom to me! And probably my choice too. Well, in my case "cba mate".

Comment: Apparently this is a British English idiom (e.g., [Where does “can't be arsed” come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14566)),  but certainly not US or Canadian idiom, where "can't be assed" doesn't quite click.

Comment: Mhmm, my bad. I've been using it since ages without realising it's an idiom. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

"I don't know, what?" (Insert *when, who, why, where* as appropriate).

This usually cuts the guessing short and gets straight to the question without being rude, and also acknowledging that you are unable to guess, which may well be why the question is asked in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

***I have no idea***. That's the most used idiom for this situation. It implicitly means you don't know and don't want to guess.

TFD(idiioms):

> **[have no idea](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+no+idea)**
>
> To not be aware of or know more information about something.
>
> A: "Is Sally off today?" B: "Oh, *I **have no idea***. Ask Elaine, she'll
>   know."
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how snarky you wanted to be, you could go with

**I *could* care less, but I'd have to try really hard**

Answer (score 0):

## No.

Possibly a little harsh depending on your tone (maybe that's what you want?) but the simplest response:

> **Them**: Can you guess what I'm doing/thinking?
>
> **You**: No.